# How to parse IP Packet in java

Tags: java, android, networking, ip

I want to parse a ip packet received in a ByteBuffer from the Tun device on a Android device. My aim is to extract the source and destination ip information from that ip packet.

Any pointers will be appreciated

Comment: Were you able to get the destination ip and port ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [the JBBP library](https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser) which is compatible with Android and [its example of parsing TCP packet](https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser/blob/master/jbbp/src/test/java/com/igormaznitsa/jbbp/it/NetPacketParsingTest.java)